# Echoing a div every 3 rows of a MySQL table

Tags: php, html

```
                    <?
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $selection = "SELECT steamUsername, steamid64, twitter, discord, github FROM hnTeam";
                $result = $conn->query($selection);

                ?>

                <div class="card-group">

                <?

                if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  


                        /*if($result->num_rows === 1 || $result->num_rows % 3 === 0) {
                            echo "<div class='card-group'>";
                        }*/

                        echo "<div class='card'>";
                        echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='...' alt='Profile picture'>";
                        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                        echo "<p class='card-text'>";
                        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-steam'></i> " . $row["steamUsername"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-discord'></i> " . $row["discord"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i> " . $row["twitter"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-github'></i> " . $row["github"] . "</span>" . "<br> <br>";
                        echo "</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";

                        /*if($result->num_rows === 1 || $result->num_rows % 3 === 0) {
                            echo "</div>";
                        }*/
                    }
                }
                ?>

                </div>

                </div>
```

There is my code so far. Essentially, I need to do the following:

For context, I will be referring to the following as a **card**:

```
                    echo "<div class='card'>";
                    echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='...' alt='Profile picture'>";
                    echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                    echo "<p class='card-text'>";
                    echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-steam'></i> " . $row["steamUsername"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                    echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-discord'></i> " . $row["discord"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                    echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i> " . $row["twitter"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
                    echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-github'></i> " . $row["github"] . "</span>" . "<br> <br>";
                    echo "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
```

Okay, so what I need to do is, every 3 **cards** need to be put into this div: `<div class='card-group'>`.

I tried some if statements as shown in the code block, however to no avail. From what I understand I need to echo it into a div once and after that echo it into a div every group of 3 cards. I tried to base the if statement on $result->num_rows but that isn't procedural, it constantly appears as the final amount of cards, it doesn't increase by 1 each run through.

I'm stumped here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Modulo http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php some one else find a dupe ;-)

Comment: Although mod will do it, its a confusing monster sometimes until thy head is wrapped firmly around its behavior. So, reading up on it before just blindly using some code someone may post... would be most beneficial in the long run.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php is my lazy goto when needing to build sets of data from an array, From there you have an outer loop generating your "rows" and an inner loop generating your "columns"

Comment: Um... weren't you doing that? `/*if($result->num_rows === 1 || $result->num_rows % 3 === 0) {`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That didn't actually work when I tried it. Because $result->num_rows returns the final amount of rows, not the current amount of rows it wasn't working as planned. It's sort of difficult to explain.

Comment: And to everyone else above - thank you for all the responses, I'm heading off for the night now however I'll look them over in the morning and I'll begin work on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You use the % operator with $result->num_rows, that is not correct, you must use the current iteration, so I added a $c var.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $c = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

        if ($c % 3 === 0) {
            if ($c > 0) {
                echo "</div>"; //Close before one
            }

            echo "<div class='card-group'>";
        }

        echo "<div class='card'>";
        echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='...' alt='Profile picture'>";
        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
        echo "<p class='card-text'>";
        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-steam'></i> " . $row["steamUsername"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-discord'></i> " . $row["discord"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i> " . $row["twitter"] . "</span>" . "<br>";
        echo "<span id='social'><i class='fab fa-github'></i> " . $row["github"] . "</span>" . "<br> <br>";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        $c++;

        if ($c == $result->num_rows) {
            echo "</div>"; //Close last one
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read my duplicate link, I recommend that you not bother checking `$result->num_rows` on every iteration.  Just put it outside of your loop and check `if(num_rows)`.  Otherwise your approach is the same as one of the three approaches that I posted on the pre-existing page.  You also don't need an `if($result->num_rows > 0){` if you have a `while()`